# How to subtract one month using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a current month generated using moment().format('MMM YYYY'). I need to get last six months using this current month.

How to subtract one month using moment.js?

Comment: They hide that sort of information in the docs (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Comment: Read [Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) `moment().subtract(1, 'month');`

Comment: @Satpal but this doesn't work `moment("2017-12-01").subtract(1, 'months');`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

For substracting in moment.js:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'months').format('MMM YYYY');
```

**Documentation:**

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

> Before version 2.8.0, the moment#subtract(String, Number) syntax was
>   also supported. It has been deprecated in favor of
>   moment#subtract(Number, String).

```
  moment().subtract('seconds', 1); // Deprecated in 2.8.0
  moment().subtract(1, 'seconds');
```

> As of 2.12.0 when decimal values are passed for days and months, they
>   are rounded to the nearest integer. Weeks, quarters, and years are
>   converted to days or months, and then rounded to the nearest integer.

```
  moment().subtract(1.5, 'months') == moment().subtract(2, 'months')
  moment().subtract(.7, 'years') == moment().subtract(8, 'months') //.7*12 = 8.4, rounded to 8
```

Comment: But this doesn't work `moment("2017-12-01").subtract(1, 'months');`

Comment: @shinzou Which version of MomentJs are you using ? I tried and no problems were encountered: http://jsfiddle.net/kzo3e3bs/4/

Comment: this doesn't work `moment("2017-12-01").subtract(1, 'months');` but this does: `moment("2017-12-01").subtract(1, 'months').format('MMMM DD h:mm A');` why the format is necessary?

Comment: It works also well without any _format()_ : http://jsfiddle.net/kzo3e3bs/7/

Comment: That's really odd: https://i.imgur.com/YJYGdf2.png and if you print the two variables: https://i.imgur.com/c0xP3Dj.png they're the same... how is this possible?

Comment: @shinzou First screen when you print the variables, look at the __d_ property of your momentjs object. And for the second screen when you're using the developper tools: _format()_ return a string, and without format you're just returning a _momentjs_ object, but the substract function is working anyway (again, look at the __d_ property)

Comment: moment().subtract(29, 'days');